# Sending data from TableView to new ViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue, uistoryboard

[image]I have created a segue between two viewControllers called "PassCell". The first has a tableView that I am attempting to send data from upon cell selection.

Ads Controller contains the code snipper Below. Redeem Controller contains `var single_ad: ADS?` which is the same class defining `advertisments` var.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "PassCell"{
        let VC = segue.destination as! RedeemController
        VC.single_ad = sender as? ADS
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let advert = advertisements[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "PassCell", sender: advert)
}
```

Everything loads but upon selection of a cell I receive an error: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'PassCell''

In my storyboard though, there is definitely a segue between these two controllers called "PassCell".

Comment: Add an image please while selecting the segue and the sidebar shows the segue identifier.

Comment: Does anything look off about this?

Comment: So where is the table view? And are you sure `performSegue(withIdentifier: "PassCell", sender: advert)` is inside `AdsController` class?

Comment: Yes. Table view is defined outside of storyboards but exists in AdsController.